# Failed to get video thumbnail from AVPlayer using Fairplay HLS

Tags: swift, avfoundation, tvos, http-live-streaming, fairplay

I'm trying to build a custom progress bar for a video player app in tvOS, and would like to show thumbnails of the video while the user scans the video.

I'm using `AVPlayer` and Fairplay HLS to play remote video files. I've tried to do this using 2 methods. One with `AVAssetImageGenerator`'s `copyCGImage`, and the other with `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`'s `copyPixelBuffer` method. Both return nil.

When I tried with a local video file, the first method worked.

Method 1:

```
let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: playerItem.asset)
let progressSeconds = playerItem.duration.seconds * Double(progress)
let time = CMTime(seconds: progressSeconds, preferredTimescale: 5)
if let imageRef = try? imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil) {
   image = UIImage(cgImage:imageRef)
}
```

Method 2:

```
let videoThumbnailsOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: [String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)])
player?.currentItem?.add(videoThumbnailsOutput)

if let pixelBuffer = videoThumbnailsOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time, itemTimeForDisplay: nil) {
   let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is generally done server side and that thumbnails are part of the manifest...

Comment: If so, how does one get the thumbnails from the manifest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually done by making use of the trick play stream associated to your actual stream.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick_mode

You can find it declared with the key EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF in the manifest of your HLS stream. A regex might be needed in order to parse its value.

```
"#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF[^#]*URI=[^#]*"
```

Once you have the URL of the trick play stream, you can use a paused instance of AVPlayer as a thumbnail. And when the user swipe left and right, you should seek the player in the thumbnail to show the right frame.

Comment: The problem is that the seeking is taking a second or two per seek, and I would like to have it instant like the Apple player provides. Do you know of a way, maybe to pre-load all the (reduced) video, so that it happens faster?

Comment: I am new to AVPlayer and want to add trick play just like YouTube. I went through the many docs but not able to find anything. Is the trick play functionality supported by AVPlayer for iOS? For Apple TV it is supported: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/techtalks-apple-tv/6/

Comment: And this works even if the I-FRAME-STREAM is protected with Apple Fairplay DRM?

Comment: Does anyone have a sample code for that?